# Locked out of Tablet

Tags: tablet, locked-out

I have been locked out of my tablet by someone who is asking for money to unlock it.  I was given 3 days to do this.  I know it is a scam.  How do I unlock my tablet?

Comment: What kind of lock is that? Is it a screen lock or something else? If screen lock, then do a factory reset. The malware must be a device administrator if it has locked the screen.

Comment: We need more information, such as what device, what type of lock, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The likelihood of you being locked out of your tablet again after entering is very high if it is a virus, you can take your important data such as photos off with a computer.
If you have root, adb and USB debugging you can reset the lock by typing this into adb;

- adb shell
- su
- rm/data/system/locksettings.db
- rm/data/system/locksettings.db-wal
- rm/data/system/locksettings.db-shm
- REBOOT

As a last resort you can re-download the system image and flash using something like twrp and then install apps again from the play store. Google now saves app data for some apps so you won't lose everything and some data is synced to your account.

Comment: mksh (the default shell in Android) isn't *case-insensitive*, so your command `REBOOT` would not work.

Comment: No, reboot can simply be achieved by holding the power button down. My apologies for not stating this before. If you require it to be done through adb then the command is "reboot -p"